# Can i revoke all of my ios certificates and get new ones?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have a new mac and I am trying to upload a new version of an app to the app store on xcode (current version). The problem is that I get an error that says "name has 3 iOS Distribution certificates but their private keys are not installed. Contact the creator of one of these certificates to get a copy of the private key." I tried to export the key from one of the old computers via keychain and import it on the new one and it fails to import. So my question is.. is there any harm in just revoking all of the iOS Distribution and iOS Developer certifications and having xcode request new ones? I believe this is the solution but I want to make sure before doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's explain the problem. `3 iOS Distribution certificates but their private keys are not installed.`. It means that you don't have the private key that was used to create the certificates on developer portal. You can't export it from your Keychain if you're not the creator of the certificate, on the one who actually generated the certificate can export it from his keychain.

Second, to answer your question. There is one thing to keep in mind, Xcode will request for developer certificates (AFAIK), and the ones that are really important are the distribution ones, that are used to release the app to the store.

Now if you have the developer account and you can create new distribution certificates, then you can revoke them for sure. If you are not the person that releases the app to the store, you can revoke them, since that person will have the right distribution certificate (you can ask him/her to send the certificate to you too). THE MOST IMPORTANT: if you are the one who releases the app to the store but you don't have access to the developer account, don't revoke them, you won't be able to do another release to the store.

I think I got everything covered but if you have any other questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: I am the one that releases and have access to the developer account so i think i will be okay. The only question i have is related to creating the new distribution cert. Do i create that online and download it/import to keychain or do i do that in xcode via manage certificates and clicking the plus sign. When trying to make a new one earrlier in xcode, I got the message "You already have a current iOS Distribution certificate or a pending certificate request." This implies that I need to revoke the existing ones first and then try this again correct?

Comment: I usually revoke everything and create them on the dev portal then download & install. Xcode has some issues with certificates & profiles and I don't trust it.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)